# How to make an element go away when the screen becomes smaller?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I was learning about "media queries" and how you can, for example, change the color of something if the width of the screen becomes smaller than, for example, 680  pixels:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    header {
         background:blue;
    }
}
```

I have a piece of code in the top right of my header:

```
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Login
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Sign in
            </a>
        </li>
```

How can I use media queries to say "when the screen becomes smaller than 680 px, I don't want the `Sign in` link to appear anymore.

In other words, when the screen becomes less than 680 width pixels, I want only the `Login` button to remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you cannot change the markup, you need to target the second child like this.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  header {
    background: blue;
  }
  li:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#"> Login </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#"> Sign in </a>
</li>
```

If you can change the markup, best practice is to assign a class-name.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  header {
    background: blue;
  }
  .signin {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="login">
  <a href="#"> Login </a>
</li>
<li class="signin">
  <a href="#"> Sign in </a>
</li>
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. Do you know what is the opposite of display: none? like if there is a piece that I only want to be VISIBLE when less than 680 px

Comment: You can then use `display: block`. There is an alternative called `visibility: visible` and `visibility: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide the signin link using `display: none;` in the media query `max-width: 680px`.

```
<li class="login-link">
    <a href="#">
        Login
    </a>
</li>
<li class="signin-link">
    <a href="#">
        Sign in
    </a>
</li>

<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    .signin-link {
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. Do you know what is the opposite of display: none? like if there is a piece that I only want to be VISIBLE when less than 680 px

Comment: Normally it should be `display: block;` but depends on what it should be. For example, you might want it to be `display: inline-block;` or `display: flex;` It's only judge-able according to your own needs.